# "Already up-to-date" means the branch is already merged?

Tags: git, github

```
* sshah-dev
  sshah-dev-74899
  sshah-yammer-fixes
saad_shah@M266845VKHTDD:elastica$ git merge release-2.108.0
Already up-to-date.
saad_shah@M266845VKHTDD:elastica$ git merge dev
Already up-to-date.
```

I am currently on sshah-dev, which is off-shoot of dev. First I merge dev into myself, to update myself. Then I try to merge release into myself.

The goal is to merge release into (a personal version of) dev.

The Already up-to-date message makes it look like they're all equal, however, raising a PR between release and dev shows that they're not, there are a number of commits in each that the other doesn't have.

Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: The Already up-to-date does not mean that the branches are equal, but that what you're trying to merge in is already a parent. Try `git log --graph --decorate --format=oneline --all` or `gitk --all` to confirm the shape of your graph, I would expect it to give you the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: If `git merge foo` meant *copy the tip of branch foo over my work, throwing away my work* then after `git merge foo` your branch would equal the code in `foo`. But that would also not be very useful, would it? So that's not what it means!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pushed the dev and release branches before with all the commits then this would be the order.

1. you created a new branch from dev, lets say `new_branch`.
2. you checkout out the new branch `git checkout new_branch`
3. you merged dev and release into dev, so while you are checked out on new-branch you did 
   `git merge dev`, then `git push` and then the same `git merge release`, then `git push`
4. At this point the `new_branch` should have the changes from dev and master